# Migrating game progress to a new psn account

Tags: ps4, psn

I want to completely delete my playstation network account due to the country established, so I want to create a new one. I have a game that I get for free on ps+, is there a way of migrating the game progress to the new account?

Comment: Not sure about losing progress, but you *will* lose the game and will need to purchase it again (or subscribe to PS Plus again if the game is still available there). Also, even if you can keep using your save game, you won't be able to earn Trophies on it, and you'll lose all previously unlocked Trophies too. I recommend you contact Sony Support and ask if they can change your account's region instead.

Comment: May I ask why are you creating a different account and migrating to it? You can have to different accounts on the same console, even from different regions.

Comment: @JohnoBoy because I can't buy from ps+. I have another account with different region but I can't access to the game because its ligated to the other account...

Answer (score 3):

Most (if not all) game saves are tied to your PSN account. Creating a new account would require you to start your games from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can't delete your PSN account. What you delete is a user (PSN ID) associated with it. You can reinstate any account on a different system and set it as the primary, which will bring back the cloud saves and previous purchases.

You cant switch the region associated with PSN accounts, meaning if username ME1, is in the US and you move to the UK, ME1 cant be reassigned to the UK. However, you can make a subaccount in the UK and then anything from the main account user is accessible.

Many, many people have complained about that. Most of it has to do with licencing titles and content availability, laws governing content in certain countries (for example, a user in Germany couldn't switch their region to US just to remove the censors for Wolfenstein), and it doesnt put Sony liable for breaking street date via the store as easily.

Comment: but the game progress will still being of the account I'm trying to get rid, right?...

Comment: I dont understand what youre asking

Comment: If you mean, will the game progress remain on your user account? Not if you dont keep the save game file or upload it to the cloud and sign back in under the same ID.