# Admin Account Transfer

Tags: ps4

My son has been playing games under the admin account on the PS4.  Is there any way to transfer his game progress and purchases to a non-admin account on the same console?

Comment: Look at this, it may answer your question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324489/migrating-game-progress-to-a-new-psn-account

Comment: Casting close vote per Ginge's comment ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure saved data can be moved to a non-admin account, but anything that involves online storage can't be. For instance, a single-player game's save file can be moved while a multiplayer game's cosmetics and ranking system cannot. As for games, you can activate the admin account as primary which means you keep all games and DLCs but you don't keep any account-linked cosmetics.