# Effective way to block Playstation Store without deleting/recreating users?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I'm hoping to block the Playstation Store to prevent unnecessary spending and browsing for some users on my PS4. In researching how to do this, it involves setting up Family Management and establishing a Family Manager and any Parent/Guardian accounts. Playstation also considers a child account based on age.

The Family Manager account with the original PS Plus subscription needs to be demoted to a child account, I'm having trouble finding a way to do that. The instructions [here](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Family-Account-Management-Landing?language=en_US) or [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/my-account/parental-controls/what-to-do-if-your-child-is-using-a-master-account/) would have been fine... had I known I needed to set this up immediately when I setup my PS4 and accounts. Now I have multiple accounts that have save data tied to them, and I don't want to delete save data or trophies for those accounts. [I've also read on Arqade that I can't move the save data to a brand new, properly setup account.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324489/migrating-game-progress-to-a-new-psn-account)

I've tried researching how to do this at the router level, by somehow blocking the Playstation Store's IP or ports. I'm not sure if this is doable without totally blocking all the PS4's online capabilities (i.e. online gaming and Netflix).

**Is there any way for me to restrict Playstation Store access without deleting any of my accounts?**

Comment: You can set up (kinda think it's by default actually) to ask for PS password to purchase anything from PS Store. Why not do that, if accidental purchases is your only concern?

Comment: @Elise Thanks for the reply. Part of the issue though is browsing the Playstation Store, downloading free games or looking at inappropriate screenshots (the "and browsing" part of it). I'll go ahead and apply that in the meantime.

Comment: You can't really stop a user from looking at the PlayStation store. It sounds like you're also trying to block viewing trailers and even seeing M rated trailers or screens. Correct?

Comment: @ShawnGordon That's right... But it sounds like that's not possible? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: I think it's more that you're looking to operate outside the scope of design here. While the answer was pretty accurate, it sea you're looking to block outright everything except select games. Unfortunately ads and other things associated with content you're looking to block don't have the kind of labels that the system will flag and block from the viewer. Maybe block access to the PS Store altogether. I do know in settings you can set the PlayStation to not play games over a certain ratings

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way is to create a family and not try to block individual IP addresses because you have more features on the PS4 such as internet browser and chatting which can be accessed by every user. Unfortunately you can't demote a family manager to a child account.

**Setup**

> - A user can be in only one family at a time.
> - Children are automatically added to the family of the adult who creates their user accounts. Children cannot be removed from the family they are added to, so be sure that the adult who creates a child’s user account intends to be the family manager.
> - Family managers and child family members cannot leave their family.

A family may only consist of maximum 7 members, there are 3 types of accounts you can add to the family. You can add existing or create PSN accounts and add them as child or adult. The type is based on the date of birth you put in when adding a member to the family.

- Adult with parental controls
- Adult without parental controls
- Child without parental controls and with restricted access

The fourth type of account is the family manager and is created when you setup a family for the first time.

[image: img]

I hope this answers some of your questions.

Comment: "family manager ... is created when you setup a family for the first time." Is it possible to indirectly demote the Family Manager by removing all the members of the family, then having another adult user invite that account to their family?

Comment: Also, is creating a child account as simple as creating a new user with a younger-than-18-years-old DOB? If so, I found this site: account.sonymobile.com/en-US/#/signin which allows a Sony Entertainment Account to change its DOB one time. "Please note that you have a Sony account with Sony Interactive Entertainment that will be linked with this account. For such accounts, you are only allowed to update your date of birth at this time."

Comment: @zr00 I don't think it's possible to ever leave your family if you decided to create one, even if you manage to remove all members. Which is a bad design IMO.

Comment: @zr00 If you decide to add child accounts you can do this via the family management, even if the account already had a DOB set you can enter the "family DOB" there (if that makes sense). I'm not sure about your link sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you want, but there are also system level controls.  You can reach these by going to [PS4 System Restrictions](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/restrict.html)

```
Settings -> Parental Controls/Family Management -> PS4 System Restrictions
```

You'll be asked to set up a PIN.

In the "Age Level for Games" section, you can set the age area you want to restrict to.  The name is misleading, because this also controls what content is shown in the store.   I.e. if you set this to "13", the store won't show M rated content.

Note that since this is not by account, it will restrict anyone who uses the console.

Comment: It's not quite my end goal... but good to know this is an option, since what I want may not be possible based on Sony's design.